# How do I maintain the formatting of text in a cell in an Excel spreadsheet when importing into R markdown?

Tags: r, excel, r-markdown, kableextra, kable

I have an .xlsx file in which some of the cells have boldface numbers and some have italicized numbers. I am using read_xlsx to read the .xlsx file into R and then using kable to present it with this code:

```
knitr::kable(spreadsheet, format="latex", booktabs = T) %>% 
kable_styling(latex_options = c("striped"))
```

I cannot get the boldface and italics numbers from the .xlsx to stay boldface and italicized when they appear in the .pdf generated from the .Rmd file. How do I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In answer to your question, you cannot maintain the formattting, but you can replicate it.

When the `read_xlsx()` function is run, it extracts the data from the cells but does not retain any of the formatting. As a result, any bold font will not be automatically transferred to R.

The easiest way of achieving what you want would be to add the bold text after you have loaded the data into R. The [kableExtra](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/kableExtra/index.html) is perfect for doing such things. Here is an example, using the `column_spec` and `row_spec` functions to change the format of the cells:

````
```{r}
library(kableExtra)

knitr::kable(iris[1:5,], format = "latex", booktab = TRUE) %>%
  column_spec(1, bold = T) %>%
  row_spec(0, bold = T, color = "red")

```
````

[image]

You can customise a number of properties (run `?row_spec`to load the helper):

- Font size
- Alignment
- Text Angle
- Text Colour
- Background Colour

If you need more fine tuning of cell formatting to specific cells, you can investigate the `cell_spec` function.

> View the full guidance for customising LaTeX tables here: https://haozhu233.github.io/kableExtra/awesome_table_in_pdf.pdf